# Парсинг ip адресов из файла

Tags: c#

Как можно спарсить ip адреса из файла? Пытался занести все данные в массив, потом из этого массива спарсить ip адреса, но ничего не получалось. Если не сложно, предоставьте пример.

P.S. Файл с ip адресами выглядит так:

> Текст 127.0.0.1 и дальше текст.

P.S.S. Пожалуйста, напишите пример подробно.

Comment: Пример файла бы привели целиком (ну или подробнее описали, как он выглядит). А то хотите готовое решение при неизвестных входных данных.

Comment: Входные данные: text text 127.0.0.1 48691 text. Выходные данные: 127.0.0.1 . И таких строк примерно 20-30к.

Comment: IPv6 есть? Подсети есть? Что именно у вас не получалось?

Answer (score 3):

http://ideone.com/eW5yrp

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string cur;
        var ips = new List<string>();

        while ((cur = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
            foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(cur, @"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"))
                ips.Add(m.Value);

        foreach (var ip in ips)
            Console.WriteLine(ip);
    }
}
```